# How to create shipping labels using FedEx web services?

Tags: web-services, fedex

I have created FedEx developer account for testing and now i would like to create shipping labels using FedEx web services. I can not find an example of creating shipping labels, ideally i would like to post a HTTP request and get the shipping label as response or achieve the same result by a SOAP request.
For a beginner like me the FedEx documentation is confusing any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is a bit confusing, but it's the best resource there is for FedEx web services. That documentation is available [here](https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/webhelp/ws/2018/US/index.htm#t=wsdvg%2FIntroduction.htm).

You'll be using the "Ship Service" to create shipping labels. The FedEx services can take either SOAP or plain XML requests. I prefer to use plain XML. In that case you can POST a request to https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/xml (the test/development server). For SOAP I think you use https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/.

There are some example request/response pairs in the documentation to get you started. Look in the section Ship Service -> Sample Transactions.

I hope this is enough to get you started.

Comment: Yes the document is bit confusing, and thanks for giving some instructions i have successfully created the shipping label.

Comment: The link seems broken. Here's a replacement: [FedEx_WebServices_DevelopersGuide_v2019](https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/downloads/pdf/2019/FedEx_WebServices_DevelopersGuide_v2019.pdf)